# Using JavaScript, how do you create a new object based on the previous one while moving the updated field at the end?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object like that:

```
const originalObject = {
  joe: true,
  mark: false,
  tonio: true,
  angela: true
}
```

I want to create a new object where mark is at true and is moved at the end.

Note that mark may or may not exist in the original object.

Currently I do it like that:

```
const update = {
  mark:true
}

const newObject = {...originalObject, ...update}
```

What gives:

```
const newObject = {
  joe: true,
  mark: true,
  tonio: true,
  angela: true
}
```

But I need:

```
const newObject = {
  joe: true,
  tonio: true,
  angela: true,
  mark: true,
}
```

I could use delet or make a for loop that iterate over all fields but I guess there is a smarter way to do that ?

Comment: The ordering of properties in an object is controlled by fixed rules of the runtime. Depending on that as the basis of some functionality in your code is seriously unwise. If you need properties in a particular order, maintain an *array* of property names separately and keep it ordered however you like.

Comment: object are key / value system. there is no order. except on es7 where you need to do your specific code for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is little weird because order of keys does not matter in object. even though here you can try like this.

```js
const originalObject = {
  joe: true,
  mark: false,
  tonio: true,
  angela: true
}
let s = {...originalObject};

delete s.mark
s.mark = true;

console.log(s)
```

Another way of doing it

```js
const originalObject = {
  joe: true,
  mark: false,
  tonio: true,
  angela: true
}
let { mark, ...result } = originalObject;
result.mark = true;
console.log(result);
```

Read this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you want to have an object?

If you want to have the elements in a specific order you have to use arrays.

Comment: I can only extract object from the database. Of course I could convert it to an array. Apparently the order is kept so this does not seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you shouldn't be using `Object` where you would need vaules to be in a specific order. Assuming you have valid usecase to use object, you can "Shift the property" to the end using `destructuring using dynamic keys`.

```
const shiftKey = (obj, key) => {
    const { [key]: toBeShifted, ...others } = obj;
    return { .
       ..others, 
       [key]: toBeShifted,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a spearate array with the keys and access your new object with these keys

```
const updatedKeys = Object.keys(originalObject).concat(Object.keys(update))
...
const markIsTrue = newObject[updatedKeys[updatedKeys.length - 1]] // for newest entry
```